Is Israeli and Palestinian natural gas sold anywhere beyond the Middle East?
Is the gas developed in Israeli and Palestinian offshore gas fields sold anywhere beyond the Middle East? As far as I know, Egypt and Jordan are the main buyers of the Israeli gas (and the Palestinian Gas is likely to pass through Israel), and there are plans to export some gas to Europe via EastMed pipeline, which is however not built yet. I wonder however whether Israel is selling gas in liquefied form or perhaps some of the gas sold to Egypt is liquefied and sent beyond the ME.

According to your link Gaza has rights to some offshore gas fields but currently no drilling happens there, it is not even under construction. So currently Gaza is not selling any gas to  anyone because it is no producing any.

It turns out that the Arab Gas pipeline, originally built for exporting Egyptian gas to Jordan, Lebanon, and Israel is now used in reverse mode to export Israeli gas to Egypt, where it is liquefied and exported to Europe (mostly Spain, which has the highest number of gas terminals in EU.)
According to this source:

Israel depended on Egyptian gas for up to 40% of its needs from 2008 to 2011, before Egypt unilaterally terminated its agreement with Israel after the 2011 revolution. This decision, in addition to the repeated attacks on the gas pipeline between the two countries, prompted Israel to sue Egypt in international arbitration courts for failing to meet the terms of its export contracts. In an effort to settle the dispute and avoid court-levied penalties, Egypt agreed to a new deal to import gas from Israel for 15 years starting in 2020, after Israel discovered large reserves in the Leviathan and Tamar fields in the Mediterranean. Egypt now imports Israeli gas —coming in through the same pipelines that used to pump gas to Israel—and then liquefies it and sends it on to Europe, taking a fee for the passage of Israeli gas through the national natural gas network. Israel exported 5.81 billion cubic meters of gas to Egypt in 2022, up 37% from 2021.

Also:

Egypt entered the natural gas export market in the early 2000s after a series of offshore hydrocarbon discoveries, investing heavily in transnational pipelines and LNG terminals under the Hosni Mubarak regime. These investments came with export contracts that were controversial due to unfair pricing, which cost Egypt more than USD10 billion at the time, according to experts. In 2003, Egypt began exporting gas to Jordan and Israel through the Arab Gas Pipeline, and its first shipment of LNG was exported to Spain in 2004.

(image source)

(image source)

Current LNG facilities in Levant (see also here):

Future EastMed pipeline, which could transport gas directly to Europe:

Related:
The prospect of Eastern Mediterranean gas production: An alternative energy supplier for the EU?
Israel, Egypt plan new gas pipe that could boost Europe supplies: Israeli ministry
East Mediterranean Gas Forum
